# Display all posts from a certain category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm looking to display all posts from a certain category on a page, I currently have Posts & Category models linked by a HABTM relationship. I want to be able to click the link on my index.html.erb and go through to a page that lists all the posts which belong to that certain category.

Do I need to create a controller for category and new routes?

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

**Index.html.erb (My current way to display the category for each post)**

```
<% post.categories.each do |category| %>
  <% category.posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= link_to category.name, post_url(post) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

** Update **

After Answer routes have been produced as below.

```
          category_posts GET    /categories/:category_id/posts(.:format)          posts#index
                     POST   /categories/:category_id/posts(.:format)          posts#create
   new_category_post GET    /categories/:category_id/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
  edit_category_post GET    /categories/:category_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
       category_post GET    /categories/:category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
                     PATCH  /categories/:category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                     PUT    /categories/:category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                     DELETE /categories/:category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
          categories GET    /categories(.:format)                             categories#index
                     POST   /categories(.:format)                             categories#create
        new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                         categories#new
       edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)                    categories#edit
            category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                         categories#show
                     PATCH  /categories/:id(.:format)                         categories#update
                     PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                         categories#update
                     DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                         categories#destroy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest posts inside categories

```
resources :categories do
  resources :posts
end
```

This will make routes like `categories/1/posts` and URL helpers like `category_posts_path(1)` where 1 is the category ID. Then in your posts controller, you will have `params[:category_id]` available which can lookup the category and then fetch the posts. Something like

```
if params[:category_id]
  @category = Category.find params[:category_id]
  @posts = @category.posts
else
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

Comment: Thanks Logan for the detailed answer! How would I go about linking to the category in my index view? Also is there anyway to change the URL to be the name attribute instead of the id?

Comment: Run `rake routes` to see your possible routes. With Logans explanation you will have categories_post_path which will lead you to a specific category.

You can use to_param to make the name of the category to a parameter.

Comment: Thanks Klausinho - appreciated!

Comment: @klausinho How would I go about doing the to_param?

Comment: @klausinho Currently getting **undefined local variable or method `categories_post_path'** from putting **<%= link_to category.name, categories_post_path %>**

Comment: I mentioned the correct path helper in my post, `category_posts_path(<category_id>)`. `categories_post_path` is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Have to do it as answer:

In your Category model:

```
def to_param
  name
end
```

But please accept Logan's anwer as the correct one, because he solves your original problem.

Comment: How would I display the link to the category in my view?

Comment: A bit confusing with the comments and answers. Okay, did you follow Logan's suggestions? What ist the result of `rake routes`?

Comment: Added Routes to the Question

Comment: Okay, sorry, my fault: It must be `<%= link_to category.name, category_posts_path %>`

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:category_id] Getting this error for some reason.

Comment: Oh wait... I just noticed that you want to have the category shown..

`<%= link_to category.name, category_path %>`

Comment: <%= link_to category.name, category_path(category.name) %> This worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def index 
 if params[:category_id]
  @posts = Post.where("category_id = ?", params[:category_id])
 else
   @posts = Post.all
 end 
end
```

An alternative to Logan's Answer as in some cases it might not work.